# Show current page featured image in sidebar

Tags: post-thumbnails

How do I call the current post's featured image in the sidebar? and if there is none, then a backup image?

Comment: what the heck is that?

Comment: That means that you didn't accept answers to your Qs as such (and therefore mark them as solution - the check mark right below the votes). Point is that you really need to comment on answers if they are not your solution. And if they are what you were searching after, then you should mark it. See "**Housekeeping Note**" by Chip Bennet below. Please go back and mark your solutions.

Comment: always good to read the rules! Thanks I get it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're going to be outputting this on a singular page (Post, Page, Attachment)?

If so, the easiest thing to do is to put your post AND sidebar content *inside* the Loop, so that you have access to the `$post` global, and post-related template tags.

Alternately, you could define a variable, *inside* the Loop, to hold `$post-ID` so that you can reference it *outside* of the Loop, i.e. in your sidebar.

In either case, *inside* the Loop, you would have e.g.:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
```

Then, in your sidebar:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) ) {
    the_post_thumbnail( 'sidebar_post_thumbnail' );
} else {
    // code to output your default image
}
```

Note: I'm assuming you'll create a custom image size to output in the sidebar, e.g.

```
add_image_size( 'sidebar_post_thumbnail', 150, 9999, false );
```

(which goes in `functions.php`, of course)